# 'Inconsistent accessibility' error when exposing a public property of a nested private type

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something and I came across an error that I cannot understand why.

```
public static class XYZ
{
    private class Foo : SomethingIWantToInheritFrom
    {
        public Foo()
        {

        }
    }

    public static Foo Bar = new Foo();
}
```

This is giving me the following error related to the `Bar` property:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'XYZ.Foo' is less accessible than field 'XYZ.Bar'

Why does this error happen?

Am I not allowed to create a static property that has the same type of a class inside my static class?

**Edit**: `Bar` needs to be public so I can access it like `Foo.Bar`. What I don't want is for other code to have access to the `Foo` class.

Comment: Remove the "public" from "static Foo Bar = new Foo();"

Comment: But it needs to be public so I can access it by `Foo.Bar`

Comment: Then the class needs to be public too. (Or they could both be internal.) Basically, you can't expose a property saying "Well here's a property, but you're not allowed to know about its type." You could change the property declaration to `public static object Bar = new Foo();` if you really wanted... but the declared type can't be more private than the declaration itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet But then other code will be able to access that type, which I don't want to

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, that make much more sense now, I think that is the explanation I was expecting, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do makes no sense. You want your callers to be able to call `XYZ.Bar`, but they don't get to know the type of the object they get back.

You could change the type of the Bar property to `SomethingIWantToInheritFrom`, if that is a public type.

Comment: Yes, you suggestion is the best fit for me, I need to make `Bar` of the type `SomethingIWantToInheritFrom`, I just didn't realized that, thanks!